# How to show automatically plank in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: autostart, plank

After I installed Plank and I clicked it, the plank show up. but if I restart or turn on the laptop. The Plank not automatically opened (show). How can I show automatically show Plank after reboot or turn on the laptop?